# RecyclerView с баннерами через 5 item - ов

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Есть `RecyclerView (LinearLayoutManager)` с объявлениями. Мне нужно чтобы баннеры (`static Integer BANNER_VIEW = 2`) выходили через каждые 5 объявлений при этом  нужно чтобы он не заменял объявления (`static Integer PUB_VIEW = 1`). Пытаюсь это реализовать но не как не могу понять как?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну можно что-то типо этого сделать.

```
private int VIEW_ITEM = 1;
private int VIEW_BANNER = 2;
private int BANNER_PERIOD = 5;

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.size() + mData.size() / BANNER_PERIOD;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position % BANNER_PERIOD != 0 ? VIEW_ITEM : VIEW_BANNER;
}

public void getItemByPos(int position) {
    return mData[position - position / BANNER_PERIOD]; // pub item
}
```

Или с помощью наследования от базовой модели:
https://medium.com/@sreekumar_av/recyclerview-with-multiple-type-t-of-views-and-how-to-bind-without-casting-5f453e4436aa

Comment: Здравствуйте.  Метод getItemByPos  нужно использовать для вычисления какое позиции для объявления? Правильно?

Comment: Здравствуйте! Да, верно.

Comment: Спасибо большое очень помогли